# TableViewCell as Delegate not receiving anything

Tags: swift, delegates

I don't understand why my delegate doesn't 'receive' anything. Later down the road, I want to hand over a UIImage from the ViewController into a CollectionViewCell inside a TableViewCell by using the delegate. The ViewController contains a tableView and I created a custom cell with a Nib (Xib) file. Each cell contains a collectionView. The tableview's cell class is my delegate, but when the ViewController 'sends' (is that the correct term?) anything to the delegate, nothing happens. Here is the code for my viewController:

```
protocol ViewControllerDelegate {
    func delegateMethod(with string: String) 
} 

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var viewControllerdelegate: ViewControllerDelegate?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet var suggestionTableView: UITableView!
    var image = UIImage()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()         suggestionTableView.delegate = self
        suggestionTableView.dataSource = self
        suggestionTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "SuggestionTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ID")
        searchBar.delegate = self 
    } 
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ID", for: indexPath) as! SuggestionTableViewCell
        cell.currentImage = image
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
    }    
}

extension ViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        print(searchText)
        viewControllerdelegate?.delegateMethod(with: "Henlo")
    }
    
}
```

And here is my TableViewCell class:

```
class SuggestionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var currentCollectionIndex = IndexPath()
    var currentCell = UICollectionViewCell()
    var currentImage = UIImage()
    let controller = ViewController()
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        
        controller.viewControllerdelegate = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
}

extension SuggestionTableViewCell: ViewControllerDelegate {
    func delegateMethod(with string: String) {
        print(string)
    }
    
}

extension SuggestionTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.userImage.image = currentImage
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    }
```

Why is my delegate not working? I am so sorry for the code mess, but stackoverflow just doesn't let me organize it properly this time...

Comment: Take a very good look at the very first two lines of code you have shown.

Comment: `let controller = ViewController()` are you sure about that?

Comment: What is wrong with the first two lines (except for the bad formatting in stackoverflow)? And what is the issue with the controller variable? I did both things as in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UQnSdXFDAQQ

Comment: I am so sorry, you must be thinking I am an idiot but I rebuilt the delegate design pattern twice now and still get nothing. It sounds like both of you know what might cause the issue, so what is it?

Comment: Could you guys please help me? I tried so many ways but still failing but it seems like its so easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

In the TableViewCell class you create an instance of ViewController class

> let controller = ViewController()

this would be a different instance than the one that created the TableViewCell hence the delegate won't be called as you are setting the delegate of the wrong instance.

Also why do you need a delegate for this? I think creating a function in the TableViewCell class should do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have to try it once the update is finished. I want to download an icon from the internet in the view controller, so the tableview will be loaded first, then I get the JSON and I want to update the cell in the CollectionView then. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you want to update the cells just call tableView.reloadData() once the download has been completed.

Comment: Your answer suggests using let controller = SuggestionTableViewCell() right? That doesn't work, because the protocol was defined in the View Controller Class or am I misunderstanding your answer? Yes I will call reloadData, but it must be called when it receives the information from the ViewController class, which is why I am using the delegate design pattern...

Comment: I am not suggesting you to use let controller = SuggestionTableViewCell(). If I am not wrong you want to set cell.currentImage of the TableViewCell. Just calling reloadData should call cellForRowAtIndexPath method and that should set the image.